Blank Screen After Ubuntu Installation and Live USB Boot, Only Accessible via Recovery Mode
I used GParted to completely clear my drive and then installed Ubuntu on my PC. After a successful installation, I rebooted the machine. However, selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu results in a blank screen. Additionally, even when attempting to boot from the live USB, it still goes to a blank screen. The only way I can access the desktop is through recovery mode. Any assitance with this will be appreciated. I also did a boot-repair and there were no changes too.
Update:
After much trials I found that I can boot directly to login by setting acpi=off in grub. This affects my soundcard and is replaced with the 'Dummy Output' in the sound settings, also I cannot connect to the external monitor with the HDMI and I cannot see battery information.

This question is similar to: My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you're using an nvidia card, I would try the nomodeset method under "Black/purple screen after you boot Ubuntu for the first time" first

How can I fix the issue of the live usb going to a blank screen?

From the live USB, pick the "Ubuntu with safe graphics" option and see if that helps

Still the same.

Then please look at the other options / answers in the linked question, try the solutions that are applicable and, if nothing avails, please edit your question explaining what you tried. Off the top of my head, if you managed to boot from the USB to install the system and then changed nothing, it doesn't make much sense that you're now unable to boot from the USB, so I wouldn't know what to suggest. I thought you maybe managed to complete the installation process using the "Safe graphics" option, but if that also doesn't work, I'm kinda at a loss.

I just observed that when I boot with recovery mode i am always able to boot the live usb. I wonder why that is though. I can't seem to find the next step from the links

You only have Ubuntu installed and no other OS and you are getting a Grub menu?

Yes. There are no other OSes on the PC.  I'm I not supposed to get GRUB?

I fixed this problem with a firmware/bios update.
